# RGB values, there is any 255 value, what's the meaning of 255?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, rgb, rgba

[image]

Value, R = 117, G = 105, B = 0, (?) = 255
...code use toast.maketext. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5):

It's the "alpha" value, which defines how *opaque* the element is. 0 = not opaque at all (completely transparent), so the other color values don't matter; 255 = completely opaque (nothing shows through it). Anything in-between is partially-opaque (semi-transparent). See [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) and [Alpha Compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

In the RGBA color model, it would be the alpha value.

Answer (score 1):

In the RGBA {117,105,0,255}

R - 117
G - 105
B - 0
Alpha - 255 ... where as alpha = 0 means - ---- completely transparent.

Answer (score 0):

There are [different color representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) that are possible.

Before processing an image I recommend you check the underlying way in which it was written.